# Automatic paragraph numbering within subsections

Tags: formatting, sections-paragraphs

I'm attempting to create a similar format to a word document (example attached) within LaTeX but I'm having a lot of issues with achieving. The document is an article and every single single paragraph requires numbering and indenting by 20mm so it would be desirable to declare this setup once rather than introducing every paragraph with \paragraph or similar.

[image]

My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,right=1.8cm,left=1.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Needed to run XeLaTeX
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section} 
    {\normalfont\huge}{\makebox[2cm][l]{\thesection}}{0pt}{} 
\titleformat{\subsection} 
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{\makebox[2cm][l]{\thesubsection}}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection} 
    {\normalfont\bfseries}{\makebox[2cm][l]{\thesubsubsection}}{0pt}{}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
    {\normalfont}{\makebox[2cm][l]{\theparagraph}}{0pt}{} 

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}
\section{This Section Header}
\paragraph{Main text.}
\subsection{Sub Section header}
\paragraph{Sub section text} 
\subsubsection{Sub Sub Section header}
\paragraph{Sub Sub section text part 1} 
\paragraph{Sub Sub section text part 2}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

But I'm not sure how to automate the paragraph numbering. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Simplistically LaTeX has two concepts for paragraphing. `\paragraph{...}` produces a numbered and titled paragraph division in the document. I the text a blank line (or `\par`)  starts a new regular paragraph as per normal documents. This construct is used in several places where you might not expect there to be a new paragraph.  I think that you are stuck with `\paragraph{...}`